# I need to combine 2 simple arrays and remove duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 simple arrays that need to be combined and sorted, easy enough. But then duplicates need to be removed.

```
oldProgrammers = new Array('Rob', 'Neek', 'Lisa', 'Susan');
newProgrammers = new Array('Brett', 'John', 'Tom', 'Lisa');

allProgrammers = oldProgrammers.concat(newProgrammers).sort();

allProgrammers.forEach(function(arrEl){
    alert(arrEl);
})
```

am clueless how this can be done?!

Comment: You could go through each consecutive pair of elements and as soon as you find two that match, remove them using .splice(indexFirstDuplicate,2)

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the dictionary data structure

```
memo = {};
oldProgrammers.map(function(i){memo[i] = 1;});
newProgrammers.map(function(i){memo[i] = 1;});
allProgrammers = Object.keys(memo);
```

`map()` is available from Javascript 1.8, and `Object.keys()` should be available after Chrome 5.

But all ***real*** browsers support it :)

Comment: This only works for strings, since property names are coerced to `String` automatically.

Comment: @nmaier He asked about merging 2 collection of strings.

Comment: I never said he didn't ;) Still wanted to make the point, to avoid having him return later when he tries to use this with something else.

Answer (score 0):

You could mash them all together (and sort them on the run) and then do go trough them with http://underscorejs.org/#uniq

> uniq_.uniq(array, [isSorted], [iterator]) Alias: unique
>
> Produces a duplicate-free version of the array, using === to test object equality. If you know in advance that the array is sorted, passing true for isSorted will run a much faster algorithm. If you want to compute unique items based on a transformation, pass an iterator function.